# when running "meteor", I get Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'

Tags: meteor

After creating a new app, I get the following error when trying to run it.

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\tsdmn\tsdmn_system\_development\_01\_01\tsdmn-webportal_dev-01-01\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

It was working a few days ago, but it just started giving me this error when I run with "meteor". I can create the app without a problem but running it gives and error.

Comment: Did you try running 'meteor npm install'?

Comment: what does "meteor npm install" do to fix this?

Comment: You are missing the Fibers NPM package. That command install the npm dependencies needed.

Comment: I have same problem after win update. `meteor npm install` doesn't work because fibers is not in `package.json` its dependency of meteor handled somewhere else. If I install fiber via npm I get another module missing. Same thing is happening after `meteor create` so it seems that update removed some meteor files(?). Have no idea... Will reinstall meter and let you know if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Meteor uses two different package management, via Atmosphere and via NPM.

Atmosphere management is done via the file .meteor/packages. Each line is added when you do a `meteor add packageName`. When you execute the `meteor` command it will read this file and download all the atmosphere dependencies.

For NPM, it's the same but the dependencies are listed in the package.json and to install all these dependencies you have to run `meteor npm install`. This will read the package.json and download everything it needs to node_modules.

For your specific case, Fiber dependency has not been download yet. You can probably see it in the package.json.

If you have just created a new app then you can see [in the guide](https://guide.meteor.com/index.html) that `meteor npm install` in necessary to set up your project.